# Is a WSDL generated by WebSphere different from one generated by a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, websphere

I am on a WCF project that is going to be interfacing with WebSphere.

They have told me that they will create a WSDL for me to call from my WCF solution.

I know ZERO about WebSphere.  So I am asking if the term WSDL is universal.  Or is it kind of like "SQL" (meaning the basics are the same, but an Oracle/WebSphere query/call may not run on SQL Server/WCF).

Has anyone tried this?  Are there hidden "gotchas"?

Comment: I'd suspect that they're the same - WSDLs are designed for interoperability (Web Service Discovery Language), so by definition they should be platform agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a purely semantic perspective both WCF WSDL's and JAX-RPC (Websphere) WSDL's are compliant with both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2. However they both tend to have some slight variations in out of the box endpoint generation, wsdl location to endpoint mapping external references location, soap:action generation and WS-* compliance that could present you issues.

IBM mentions the following as a common issue when integrating WCF generated WSDL's with their products which are based on JAX-RPC

Note: Web services allow applications to interoperate by using standard descriptions of services and standard formats for the messages they exchange. For example, the Web service import and export bindings can interoperate with services that are implemented using Web Services Enhancements (WSE) Version 3.5 and Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) Version 3.5 for Microsoft .NET. When interoperating with such services, you must ensure that:
The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file that is used to access a Web service export includes a non-empty SOAP action value for each operation in the interface.
The Web service client sets either the SOAPAction header or the wsa:Action header when sending messages to a Web service export.